# iOs Simulator running slow

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, ios8.3

Guys I really need your help. I was so concentrated running my game on iphone 5s device and I didn't realize that iphone 6 is running a little slower than the 5s and the 6 plus worst. What can I do for it?

Comment: Why do you need it to run fast in the simulator? The iPhone 6+ will be rendering your game at 2208x1242 resolution, which is too high for some GPUs to handle well. But the actual GPU in an iPhone 6+ can easily do it.

Comment: oh thank you i didn't know that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very common bug with the simulator a way I get around it is.

**IOS Simulator:** Window > Scale > 50% - it makes the simulator look like an actual device and it fits your screen perfectly.

Then  I just leave the simulator open at all times rather then closing after I'm done testing my apps. This saves Xcode having to load all the simulators files and directories each time you run your app.

Hope this helps, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try cleaning? Sometimes applications have problems.

**iOS Simulator:**
iOS Simulator Menu > Reset Content and Settings..

**Xcode:**
Product > Clean

Comment: I tried but it doesn't change at all. Thank you it was something new i've never tried that